# Bowers .bower.json file version property

Tags: bower

bower.json has a property named version. Bower uses tags to manage versions. I'm wondering what is this property uses for then? Does it have to match the committed tag? If not can it cause issues? Is this another way of managing versions? does bower follow this in any way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bower currently ignores `version` from `bower.json`.

If the version in bower.json doesn't match git tag, you get a warning, and the `version` entry in generated `.bower.json` is fixed (`version` in `bower.json` stays the same).

Among others that's why bower plugins should consume`.bower.json` instead `bower.json`.

You can safely remove `version` from your `bower.json`. Bower only respects git tags.

Most probably it won't be used even in the future.

Comment: If you want to keep `version` in `bower.json` file in sync with `package.json`, here is a small Node.js script [verup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/verup) to help you do so.
I've built this script to help me update `version` in all project files (like `config.js`, `config.php` etc)

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that bower simply uses the git tags available at the git endpoint submitted during `bower register`. Most of the info in `bower.json` is currently mainly used for the package's own record keeping, and isn't kept by the bower registry.

The bower team plans to take advantage of the valuable info in `bower.json` in the future (discussed [here](https://github.com/bower/registry/issues/73)).